# Unable to get width of <rect element of <svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, typeerror

I am trying to access last `"rect"` so that I can get its width and height. I tried following jquery `$(".highcharts-plot-background").width()` but all I get in answer is 0. Also tried to use `$(".highcharts-plot-background")[0].width()` but then I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).width() is not a function.

I am open to suggestions.

```html
<svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="710" viewBox="0 0 710 325" height="325">
  <desc>Created with Highcharts 5.0.0</desc>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="highcharts-1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="636" height="238" fill="none"></rect>    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="710" height="325" rx="0" ry="0"></rect>
  <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="64" y="50" width="636" height="238" style="margin:0px;"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attr("width")` instead of `width()`. If you would have been declaring the width in the css then `width()` would work just fine.

See the snippet below.

```js
console.log($(".highcharts-plot-background").attr("width"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="710" viewBox="0 0 710 325" height="325">
  <desc>Created with Highcharts 5.0.0</desc>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="highcharts-1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="636" height="238" fill="none"></rect>    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="710" height="325" rx="0" ry="0"></rect>
  <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="64" y="50" width="636" height="238" style="margin:0px;"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking jQuery takes care of these things.